# load jquery script in ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi i have jquery script for image gallery which can add the dynamic divs around the record and show the divs in columns and set the column width according to the page width.
Now i have a search option which can query the same record but in Ajax that can  not add the dynamic divs because the page is not refreshed??
How i can run the jquery script in Ajax call,
when i can add the following script in the ajax page the hover effect works but still the dynamic divs not adde

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.mosaicflow__item').hoverdir();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Simplest solution is to use `jQuery('.mosaicflow__item').hoverdir();` in success callback

Comment: @Satpal can i include the libraries in the ajax call also???

Comment: Yes you can, It would be great if you show us some code

Comment: how i can append the following script in the example in in jquery ??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad any hint for my last comment?